# File upload returns error even if image size way below upload_max_filesize

Tags: php

When I try to upload an image over about 4mb, then $_FILES['upload']['error'] returns 1 and the file wont upload. But in my php.ini I have upload_max_filesize set to 20mb....

Why am i getting an error?

Heres php code to check for error

```
if ($_FILES['upload']['error']) {
   array_push($not_uploaded, $_FILES['upload']['name']);
   if ($_FILES['upload']['error'] == 1) {
     trigger_error('Iimage exceeded server php upload limit', E_USER_WARNING);
     array_push($error_msgs, elgg_echo('services:image_mem'));
   } else {
     array_push($error_msgs, elgg_echo('services:unk_error'));
          }
 }
```

Comment: phpinfo(), make suer its the right php.ini file; most systems would have 2 at least (cli, and via Apache)

Comment: Could you please post your php code, thanks!

Comment: Several other places could be setting that .. a phpinfo(); will tell you what the settings it's using actually are, and where they are being gotten from.

Comment: Do you have the `MAX_FILE_SIZE` hidden field in the correct place?

Comment: I just found that upload_max_filesize is also set in .htaccess and its set to 5242880. This is probably the value used (phpinfo() says upload_max_filesize is 20m). But still, the files im trying to upload are 4.5 and 4.7mb but an error of 1 is still being returned..

Comment: @TweetWithThisOwl_FollowMe I will edit post to show the php check im doing

Comment: @Eugen Rieck I dont have a MAX_FILE_SIZE. Is that some sort of client side check that can be done?

Comment: First, try setting upload_max_filesize to 20M instead of 20m. Then, check your post_max_size setting. It also needs to be set to >= upload_max_filesize.

Comment: yeah upload_max_filesize is set to 20M in php.ini and ive now set it to 20M in .htaccess. Still getting an error..

Comment: @Dragon you were right, the php.ini in cli was over-writing the values set in the other php.ini and .htaccess

Comment: @Elijah Madden thanks for the help, it was my fault, i didnt realize the cli php.ini and over-writing everything i was changing

Answer (score 2):

You should also check the configuration of the variable post_max_size in the php.ini file.

In PHP docs: [Common Pitfalls](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php)

> If post_max_size is set too small, large files cannot be uploaded.
>   Make sure you set post_max_size large enough.

Answer (score 0):

As the [php docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) say, you need to send a (most often hidden) field with the name `MAX_FILE_SIZE` before the actual file. While theoretically even 4MB shouldn't work without it, this might be some hardcoded default.

Use the example form of the mentioned PHP docs page as a starting point.

Comment: oh I didnt know about MAX_FILE_SIZE, i thought i had to always check file size after its up loaded. This is useful:)

Comment: Actually MAX_FILE_SIZE is only an indication, and most browser's just ignore it, you always have to upload the file to check it's size in PHP.

Comment: @Tio MAX_FILE_SIZE is **not only** for the Browser, it is also sent as a `POST` variable, and parsed by PHP. This doesn't mean, you can use it to bypass the limits in `php.ini`

Comment: @EugenRieck, yes, your right, I forgot to mention that the MAX_FILE_SIZE is sent by POST